# How to automatically start Nodered on boot?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red

I want to automatically start nodered on boot. I'm using a raspberry 3 model B v2.

According to those instructions "https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/raspberrypi" , I have install and create a flow.

I'm using 
Node-RED version: v0.20.7
Node.js  version: v8.16.0

When I start nodered using `node-red-pi --max-old-space-size=256`
it's working perfectly.

But now I want to use it as a service and launch it automatically.
Following the same instructions, I ran the command `sudo systemctl enable nodered.service`. The `reboot`, and nothing happened. Nodered didn't start.

I tried to run it directly as a service using `node-red-start`, and I got this error message

---

```
Starting as a systemd service.
Unit nodered.service entered failed state.
nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Stopping Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Starting Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
/usr/bin/env: node-red-pi: No such file or directory
nodered.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Unit nodered.service entered failed state.
nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Stopping Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Starting Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
/usr/bin/env: node-red-pi: No such file or directory
nodered.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Unit nodered.service entered failed state.
nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Stopping Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Starting Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
/usr/bin/env: node-red-pi: No such file or directory
nodered.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Unit nodered.service entered failed state.
nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Stopping Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Starting Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
/usr/bin/env: node-red-pi: No such file or directory
nodered.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Unit 
nodered.service entered failed state.
nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Stopping Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
Starting Node-RED graphical event wiring tool...
nodered.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Failed to start Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
Unit nodered.service entered failed state.
```

---

Has someone an idea about this error and how to fix it?
There is another way to start nodered automatically?

Comment: The error `/usr/bin/env: node-red-pi` suggests node-red hasn't installed properly. Try rerunning the `update-nodejs-and-nodered` script from the documentation. If it still fails, come talk to us on the forum where we can debug it better. SO isn't the best place to debug an issue of this nature.

Comment: 'node-red-pi --max-old-space-size=256' uses nodered v8 and it works. But 'node-red-start' uses nodered v10 and it does not work. Do you have an idea how to configure 'node-red-start'?

Comment: I found the file node-red-start using "which node-red-start". How to force it to use nodeJS v8? I think it will solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @knolleary I'm having this issue - seems like the exact same one - I've posted on the Node-Red forums as dclear - if you could help I'd be very grateful thanks

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use pm2 as a watchdog for nodeRed and to monitor its behavior.
(it's more than a watchdog, if you want to fiddle)

simply get pm2 from npm:

```
npm install pm2@latest -g
```

then run nodeRed using pm2:

```
pm2 start <PATH to nodered folder> --node-args="--max-old-space-size=128" -- -v
```

typically the path you are referring to is : /usr/bin/node-red

finally use:

```
pm2 save
```

to save the configuration and

```
pm2 startup
```

to create a startup script

to manage the process check the commands here:
[PM2 quick start](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem a while ago. you can use nohup to start it automatically or not to end the session even you close the device.

Just install nohup, and type nohup node-red. 
If you want to check status, write nohup status in the terminal.
for stoping, nohup stop node-red. Enjoy :)